# $Failed when naming the variable x

Tags: equation-solving

Total beginner here, the problem goes away when renaming x into other letters.

Below is the code

```
Solve[-2 (x - 1)*y == 1 && x + y == t, {x, y}]

{{$Failed -> 1/2 (1 + t + Sqrt[3 - 2 t + t^2]), y -> 1/2 (-1 + t - Sqrt[3 - 2 t + t^2])}, 
{$Failed -> 1/2 (1 + t - Sqrt[3 - 2 t + t^2]), y -> 1/2 (-1 + t + Sqrt[3 - 2 t + t^2])}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise.
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must clear  all values and definitions.
Use that:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

and

```
Solve[-2 (x - 1)*y == 1 && x + y == t, {x, y}]
```

> `{{x -> 1/2 (1 + t + Sqrt[3 - 2 t + t^2]),y -> 1/2 (-1 + t - Sqrt[3 - 2 t + t^2])}, {x ->1/2 (1 + t - Sqrt[3 - 2 t + t^2]), y -> 1/2 (-1 + t + Sqrt[3 - 2 t + t^2])}}`

See it:[Clear ->Documentation Center »](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html)